# What kind of table is created when executing a query that returns nothing?

Tags: python, sql, etl

I'm using petl and trying to create a simple table with a value from a query. I have written the following:

```
@staticmethod
def get_base_price(date):
    # open connection to db
    # run SQL query to check if price exists for that date
    # set base price to that value if it exists
    # set it to 100 if it doesn't
    sql = '''SELECT [TimeSeriesValue]
        FROM [RAP].[dbo].[TimeSeriesPosition]
        WHERE TimeSeriesTypeID = 12
        AND SecurityMasterID = 45889
        AND FundID = 7
        AND EffectiveDate = %s''' % date
    with self.job.rap.connect() as conn:
        data = etl.fromdb(conn, sql).cache()
    return data
```

I'm connecting to the database, and if there's a value for that date, then i'll be able to create a table that would look like this:

```
+-----------------+
| TimeSeriesValue |
+=================+
|     100         |
+-----------------+
```

However, if the query returns nothing, what would the table look like?
I want to set the TimeSeriesValue to 100 if the query returns nothing. Not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be passing in parameters when you execute the statement rather than munging the string . .  but that is not central to your question.

Possibly the simplest solution is to do all the work in SQL.  If you are expecting at most one row from the query, then:

```
SELECT COALESCE(TimeSeriesValue, 100) as TimeSeriesValue
FROM [RAP].[dbo].[TimeSeriesPosition]
WHERE TimeSeriesTypeID = 12 AND
      SecurityMasterID = 45889 AND
      FundID = 7 AND
      EffectiveDate = %s
```

This will always return one row and if nothing is found, it will put in the `100` value.

Answer (score 0):

A query that returns nothing would just display the column name(s) with nothing under them. I'd try something like this:

```
IF(TimeSeriesValue IS NOT NULL)
    <your query>
ELSE
    SET TimeSeriesValue = 100
```